# How to set default value of composite type attributes in postgres?

Tags: postgresql

Here is a user-defined type in Oracle:

```sql
TYPE type_daniel IS RECORD(
     name varchar(16) := '112',
     age int :=12,
     sex int :=1
    );
```

I want to port it to Postgres, but pg doesn't support the syntax likes:

```sql
create type type_daniel as (
     name varchar(16) := '112',
     age int :=12,
     sex int :=1
    );
```

I tried to create a table with the same name and default values:

```sql
create table test_daniel(
    name varchar(10),
    age int,
    sex int default 1
);
```

but when I use it as a variable in a procedure:

```sql
create or replace procedure test_daniel_func() as $$
    declare
        vrow test_daniel;
    begin
        vrow.name:='jzy';
        vrow.age:=23;
        raise notice '%,%',vrow.name,vrow.sex;
end
    $$
    language plpgsql;
```

then I call this procedure.

I expect the output to be `jzy,1`, but the actual output is `jzy,NULL`.

So, How to set default value of composite type attributes in postgres?

Comment: Default constraint works when ever you are doing and DML operation but in your case you are assigning the values in name and age that why sex column is null..

Comment: Yes. Do you mean when I declare a table -type variable in a procedure, pg won't exec the DML operation?

Comment: That variable is a single record and that record is not initialized through a DML statement - it's initialized thrugh the PL/pgSQL assignment that you wrote

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can do that unless you write your type in C.

You'll have to initialize the value explicitly. If you use the type in a table definition, a `BEFORE` trigger could do that for you.

Comment: Yes, it seems that compiling a C file depends on postgres lib is not an easy job. I give up this way. I wrote an exception handler to check the attributes if their value is null and if yes, the handler will assign the default value.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, then you can do this:

```
CREATE TYPE type_daniel AS (
    name VARCHAR(16),
    age INTEGER,
    sex INTEGER 
);

CREATE TABLE test_daniel OF type_daniel (
    sex WITH OPTIONS DEFAULT 1
);
```